# How to implement Global Hotkeys in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, global-hotkey

I need to write an application which globally intercepts Alt+Shift+S.

What I did is I created a DLL which sets global hooks:

```
namespace Hotkeydll
{
    public class MyHotKey
    {
        public static void setHooks()
        {
            KeyboardHookProcedure = new HookProc(KeyboardHookProc);
            hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardHookProcedure, Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]), 0);
        }

        private int KeyboardHookProc(int nCode, Int32 wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            //write something into file
        }


   }
}
```

Then I created a program which loads this DLL and set the hook:

```
using Hotkeydll;
namespace IWFHotkeyStarter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyHotKey.setHooks();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that the hotkey doesn't work.

It looks like the DLL is not loaded permanently into memory. I see that I can delete the dll file from file system.

So please advise what I am doing wrong?

Should I use a different approach?

Thank you.

Comment: What does your PInvoke code look like for `SetWindowsHookEx`

Comment: This might be helpful http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your Main() method sets the hooks, then immediately exits and terminates the program.  Furthermore, you need a message loop to make the hook callback work.  That requires a Windows Forms or WPF app.  Using a real hot key instead of a hook now also becomes an option.  Check [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/2622427d-1e15-4f30-b01d-57b0ba054f5c/) for an example, C# is further down the page.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard hooks are usually not the right way to get global hotkeys.

Use [RegisterHotkey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309(VS.85).aspx) whenever possible.

Comment: @Paedow That's the windows API. You'll need to use a fitting p/invoke method, but that's not hard.

Comment: It´s justz the thing that I am not so good at this because I´ve never learned